# What's my daily vote limit?

Tags: discussion

I've hit my daily vote limit. But where does it say what the daily vote limit is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it in [the site's FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq):

> A maximum of 30 votes can be cast per
>   user per day

For more info and background, see [this discussion on Meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/why-are-there-voting-limits).

Comment: OK, thanks I had a look for the words "vote limit" in that but didn't find them.